# How to join unrelated table in WHERE name from unrelated table is contained in text field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read all of the posts regarding unrelated table joining that I can find however none seem to have anything to help me (that I can understand).
I have 2 temporary tables and I need table 2 to only contain rows where 
the text field contains any one of the names in table1.  There is no direct link between the 2 tables.

*table 1 example:*
**table1.fullname**
a name
b name
c name
d name

*extract of 'subject' column in table 2:*
**subject**
Market Research Report on Food Exports to the Bahamas
Initial Telecon
a name - Update call to check progress
 Update call to check progress  a name
b name - Met with Anna
Advising Peter - b name
c name- Assistance to complete funding application.
d name - Advice

What I need are only the rows from table 2 that contain any of the names in table1 in the subject field.

I have used something like:
`WHERE table2.subject LIKE '%'+table1.fullname+'%'` 
but it will not work as I have not joined the tables in any way.
Most of the posts seem to suggest using a crossjoin but as both tables are very large I don't think that is the best way.
I think that I should be using a sub-query but cant work out how to join that in.
My code so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ITA', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ITA SELECT        *
INTO            #ITA
FROM            (select distinct fullname
from FilteredContact
Where (jobtitle LIKE 'International Trade Adviser%'))InternationalTradeAdviser;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ITAactivity', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ITAactivity SELECT        *
INTO            #ITAactivity
FROM            (SELECT distinct     FilteredAppointment.activityid as ActivityID, Filteredccx_project.ccx_customerid AS CompanyID,  Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectnumber AS ProjectNumber,
                                CONVERT(varchar, FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart, 103) AS ConvertedTime, 
                                FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes, FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes / 60 AS Hours, FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes % 60 AS Minutes,
                                'International Trade Adviser' As TypeOfService
                FROM            FilteredAppointment INNER JOIN
                Filteredccx_project ON FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectid = Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectid
                WHERE        (FilteredAppointment.statecode = 1) AND (FilteredAppointment.subject LIKE '%'+#ITA.fullname+'%') AND
                (Filteredccx_project.ccx_programme IN ('04D0B1DF-FD36-E611-8870-005056A52209','14286237-FE36-E611-8870-005056A52209')) AND
                Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectstatus IN(803080000,803080001) AND 
                Filteredccx_Project.ccx_runningtotal>=12)ITAactivities;
```

I tried using a sub query in the WHERE clause but that produced an error message because it returns more than 1 row.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: sorry. Will do that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that you only want records that contain the fullnames, you can use `exists` in the `where`-clause also.

To do this, replace the part

```
AND (FilteredAppointment.subject LIKE '%'+#ITA.fullname+'%')
```

with this

```
AND exists (select 1
              from #ITA it
             where FilteredAppointment.subject like '%' + it.fullname + '%')
```

The final insert would then look something like this:

```
SELECT *
  INTO #ITAactivity
  FROM (SELECT distinct
               FilteredAppointment.activityid as ActivityID,
               Filteredccx_project.ccx_customerid AS CompanyID,
               Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectnumber AS ProjectNumber,
               CONVERT(varchar, FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart, 103) AS ConvertedTime,
               FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes, FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes / 60 AS Hours, FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes % 60 AS Minutes,
               'International Trade Adviser' As TypeOfService
          FROM FilteredAppointment
                 INNER JOIN
               Filteredccx_project ON FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectid = Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectid
         WHERE (FilteredAppointment.statecode = 1)
           AND (Filteredccx_project.ccx_programme IN ('04D0B1DF-FD36-E611-8870-005056A52209', '14286237-FE36-E611-8870-005056A52209'))
           AND Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectstatus IN (803080000, 803080001)
           AND Filteredccx_Project.ccx_runningtotal >= 12
           AND exists (select 1
                         from #ITA it
                        where FilteredAppointment.subject like '%' + it.fullname + '%'))ITAactivities;
```

Comment: Nicely formatted - which is a huge improvement. For OP - there isn't any good reason to use a derived table and I suspect distinct does nothing useful. One should always specify a length with casting (varchar(?)) - style 103 has a fixed length so varchar should really be char.

Comment: it is a derived table because it needs to be and is part of a much larger query.  Thank you for the varchar/char tip.  Will try the response above now and let you know

Comment: That works beautifully. Thank you so much.  So simple but my brain just wouldn't get there.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This dynamic technique might be useful:

```
Declare @FullNames as nvarchar(max)
Declare @Sql as nvarchar(max)

select @FullNames = 
    stuff((
        select distinct ' or subject like ''%' + [fullname] + '%'''
        from t1
        for xml path('')
    ),1,3,'') as x

set @Sql = 'SELECT        *
            INTO            #ITAactivity
            FROM            (SELECT distinct     FilteredAppointment.activityid as ActivityID, Filteredccx_project.ccx_customerid AS CompanyID,  Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectnumber AS ProjectNumber,
                            CONVERT(varchar, FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart, 103) AS ConvertedTime, 
                            FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes, FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes / 60 AS Hours, FilteredAppointment.actualdurationminutes % 60 AS Minutes,
                            ''International Trade Adviser'' As TypeOfService
            FROM            FilteredAppointment INNER JOIN
            Filteredccx_project ON FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectid = Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectid
            WHERE        (FilteredAppointment.statecode = 1) AND (FilteredAppointment.subject LIKE ''%''+#ITA.fullname+''%'') AND
            (Filteredccx_project.ccx_programme IN (''04D0B1DF-FD36-E611-8870-005056A52209'',''14286237-FE36-E611-8870-005056A52209'')) AND
            Filteredccx_project.ccx_projectstatus IN(803080000,803080001) AND 
            Filteredccx_Project.ccx_runningtotal>=12)ITAactivities AND (' + @FullNames + ')'

exec(@Sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I have already used the 'exists' from the previous response, however I am grateful for the reply.  Although I have used this type of code before it is a bit beyond me but I will spend some time working through it in order to extend my learning.  Thank you again